# How to display Sitecore content tree in a dropdown inside Sitecore WFFM Action Editor window of my custom save action?

Tags: wffm, content-editor, speak

I am creating a WFFM custom save action that works based on chosen EXM message. I have created an Action Editor dialog for my save action which should give the user to option to choose the EXM message from Sitecore content tree. I am trying to display the Sitecore content tree in a dropdown(similar to droptree in Sitecore) in my action editor dialog but unable to do it so far. The action editor is xaml based dialog and I need the possibility to filter the items being displayed in the dropdown(only specific template based items should be displayed in the dropdown).

I have tried using this:

```
 <DataContext runat="server" ID="CommandsDataContext" DataViewName="Master" ShowRoot="true" Root="{0DE95AE4-41AB-4D01-9EB0-67441B7C2450}" />

            <TreePicker Width="75%" ID="MessageItem" runat="server" DataContext="CommandsDataContext" AllowDragging="false" SelectOnly="true" AllowNone="false"  Style="width:96%"/>
```

The above shows the control with a pre-selected path to **/sitecore/content/home** but the control do not show a dropdown on click.

I am using Sitecore 8.2 Update 2.

Please help.

Comment: Your code snippet seems correct and is working fine for me. I tested it in an existing action editor dialog xml using an existing ID for the Root attribute of the DataContext. The `/sitecore/content/home` path is the default path rendered in the TreePicker control if the ID of the Root data context attribute doesn't map to an existing Sitecore item. But even with a wrong ID, the TreePicker control should render a dropdown on click. Any error in the console of your browser?

Comment: @AlessandroFaniuolo There are no console errors. This works for me also if I try this with one of the xml action editor dialogs. But I am using the xaml based dialog which starts with something like this:
<xamlControls xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xaml">

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to work in a xaml based dialog. You might need to consider to build your dialog in xml instead.